# Load a series of sql files through capistrano

Tags: mysql, bash, capistrano

I'm having an issue trying to load a series of sql files through our capistrano recipe for our testing environment.

Here's what I came up to :

```
  desc "Empty database and play sql scripts for fresh db structure"
  task :mysqlrestore, :roles => :app do 

  run "find #{current_release}/migration/ -name '*.sql' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file mysql -hlocalhost -u#{db_username} -p#{db_password} #{db_database} < file"
```

My capistrano console outputs a :

> failed: "sh -c 'find /home/toolbox/www/staging/releases/20120119111819/migration/ -name '\''*.sql'\'' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -ppassword DBNAME < file'" on staging.env.com

Where could I be wrong ?

Comment: I think you're missing spaces between -u and the username, -p and the pass, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to execute your command from bash just by removing your single quotes from your run command.

**i.e.**

```
 run "find #{current_release}/migration/ -name *.sql -print0 | xargs -0 -I file mysql -hlocalhost -u#{db_username} -p#{db_password} #{db_database} < file"
```