# Using Capistrano To Run mySql Command

Tags: mysql, capistrano

I am trying to use capistrano to run a mysql command.

In my local termainal if i run

```
mysql -u <username> -p <password> -h <server ip> <database name>
```

It connects to mysql and is ready for commands.

If however i run this in a capistrano task....

```
execute "mysql -u <username> -p <password> -h <server ip> <database name>"
```

If runs without failing and just hangs there. Does this mean it is connected and waiting for a command? If so how would i provide the command?

Comment: Do you expect to be able to use it interactively, or do you have just one command to execute?  The `-e 'SELECT * FROM tbl'` command line option will run one.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i have several SQL queries that i want to run, these SQL queries will be hard coded in the task file. Do you think the fact it is hanging means it is ready to receive a command?

Comment: It looks like it, but I don't know that it is useful. I just established an SSH connection and started a mysql prompt like `ssh localhost mysql -ppasswd dbname` and got no output back, but my command didn't complete. I then typed `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl;` and still got no output until I did `ctl-d`.  After that, my query result was displayed and my prompt returned.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925461/load-a-series-of-sql-files-through-capistrano/8932883?s=7|0.9940#8932883). As an alternative to `-e` you can pipe SQL statements into `mysql` like `echo 'SELECT * FROM tbl' | mysql -ppasswd dbname`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Using -e and separating queries by semicolons works - thank you for the answer :). My only question now is why? Is there any way for me to connect to mysql in one command, run a query in the next command and then exit mysql? If i run these run commands separately in terrainal it works fine, but stringing them together in capistrano it falls down.

Comment: I think it may be possible to allocate an interactive shell with Capistrano and feed it input incrementally, but when using the mysql command line client, that seems like it would be a terrible hack.  To execute queries in a script, mysql really wants you to use STDIN or `-e/--execute`.  I can put this as an answer below if you'd like

Comment: Thats really useful thanks. Put it below and i will select it as the answer.

Comment: I hate to be that guy - why would you ever do this? I'd advise against it.

Comment: Hey @Paul - I am using this to run SQL queries as part of a Capistrano deploy process. The queries are required for the automated deployment of a Wordpress site from local to staging. Why would you advise against this and what would be the better solution in your eyes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` command line client has a few different methods of providing queries on the command line.  It can accept them with the `--execute/-e` flag like:

```
mysql --execute 'SELECT * FROM tbl' --user=user dbname
```

Or it can accept them from `STDIN` by pipe or file redirection:

```
echo 'SELECT * FROM tbl' | mysql --user=user dbname
# Or:
mysql --user=user dbname < file_containing_queries.sql
```

For your application in Capistrano, executing them via `--execute` should work well. You may delimit multiple statements with semicolons, but be sure to properly quote everything. The full set of SQL statements should be one quoted string.

```
# In a Capistrano task:
execute "mysql -e'SELECT * FROM tbl1; SELECT * FROM tbl2;' -u <username> -p <password> -h <server ip> <database name>"
```

This may be a good use of Ruby's alternative `%q/%Q` quoting to avoid issues quoting string literals inside the SQL statements:

```
execute %q{mysql -e"SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE col='value'; SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE col='value';" -u user -ppasswd -hhost dbname}
```

When launching the `mysql` client via SSH in Capistrano, it appears that the client is loaded on the server and accepting statements, but feeding them interactively would be considerably more difficult.  MySQL provides `--execute` and `STDIN` options for this reason, so it would be best to use them.